# Dynamic Graph of Sensor data with aChartEngine - Android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, graph, achartengine

I have an application which connects to an external sensor via Bluetooth Low Energy. I have the data coming in as a dynamic string which I have split into three strings, then I have the strings converted into doubles.

I have been trying to graph the doubles dynamically for weeks now with various chart libraries such as

- [aChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/)
- [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/)
- and [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots)

I decided to go with aChartEngine mainly because I found a [dynamic sample app](https://app.box.com/s/65d1c23a01430e206342) that graphs random data. I have been trying to implement this sample app into mine. Then I am hoping to adapt it to graph my sensor data `doubles`.

Here is the code I am trying to implement at the moment:

```
public class XYChartBuilder extends Activity {
public static final String TYPE = "type";

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;

private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

private String mDateFormat;

private Button mNewSeries;

private Button mAdd;

private GraphicalView mChartView;

private int index = 0;

static double x = 0;
static double y = 0;

protected Update mUpdateTask;

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
    mDataset = (XYMultipleSeriesDataset) savedState
            .getSerializable("dataset");
    mRenderer = (XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) savedState
            .getSerializable("renderer");
    mCurrentSeries = (XYSeries) savedState
            .getSerializable("current_series");
    mCurrentRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) savedState
            .getSerializable("current_renderer");
    mDateFormat = savedState.getString("date_format");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("dataset", mDataset);
    outState.putSerializable("renderer", mRenderer);
    outState.putSerializable("current_series", mCurrentSeries);
    outState.putSerializable("current_renderer", mCurrentRenderer);
    outState.putString("date_format", mDateFormat);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo_opengl_acc);

    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(10);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("TIME");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("y");
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    String seriesTitle = "Series " + (mDataset.getSeriesCount() + 1);
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
    mDataset.addSeries(series);
    mCurrentSeries = series;
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    mCurrentRenderer = renderer;

    mUpdateTask = new Update();
    mUpdateTask.execute(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView
                        .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);
                if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(XYChartBuilder.this,
                            "No chart element was clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            XYChartBuilder.this,
                            "Chart element in series index "
                                    + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                                    + " data point index "
                                    + seriesSelection.getPointIndex()
                                    + " was clicked"
                                    + " closest point value X="
                                    + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y="
                                    + seriesSelection.getValue()
                                    + " clicked point value X="
                                    + (float) xy[0] + ", Y="
                                    + (float) xy[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
        mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView
                        .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                if (seriesSelection == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(XYChartBuilder.this,
                            "No chart element was long pressed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    return false; // no chart element was long pressed, so
                                    // let something
                    // else handle the event
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(XYChartBuilder.this,
                            "Chart element in series index "
                                    + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                                    + " data point index "
                                    + seriesSelection.getPointIndex()
                                    + " was long pressed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    return true; // the element was long pressed - the event
                                    // has been
                    // handled
                }
            }
        });
        mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
            public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
                String type = "out";
                if (e.isZoomIn()) {
                    type = "in";
                }
                System.out.println("Zoom " + type + " rate "
                        + e.getZoomRate());
            }

            public void zoomReset() {
                System.out.println("Reset");
            }
        }, true, true);
        mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
            public void panApplied() {
                System.out.println("New X range=["
                        + mRenderer.getXAxisMin() + ", "
                        + mRenderer.getXAxisMax() + "], Y range=["
                        + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + ", "
                        + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + "]");
            }
        });
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        boolean enabled = mDataset.getSeriesCount() > 0;
    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
}

private int generateRandomNum() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    return randomInt;

}

protected class Update extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {

        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                x = x + 5;
                y = generateRandomNum();

                publishProgress(i);
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        // return "COMPLETE!";
    }

    // -- gets called just before thread begins
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);

        if (mChartView != null) {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = mChartView.toBitmap();
        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "test" + index++ + ".png");
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // -- called if the cancel button is pressed
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
  }
}
```

and I have "joined it" to the relevant page on the app in the xml layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".demo.DemoAccelerometerSensorActivity" >

<sample.ble.sensortag.demo.DemoGLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/gl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="93dp" />

<requestFocus />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="Now Recording Data to file. Press button to add name to file" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/AccValues"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Accelerometer"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/baddNametoFile"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"
    android:text="Add Name to File" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Stop"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:text="Stop Recording" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ETName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name Here"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:maxWidth="200dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I have implementing the project is that it does not show up in the app at all.
[image]

There are no errors. It just doesn't display. I am just wondering if anyone can help. Or if you know any other basic dynamic graph tutorials, maybe for implementing into an existing project. I am 15 (*edit - 16 now*) and have only started java in the last couple of months. I am still only at the basics. If you post any code could you please explain it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your code is fine .I checked on devices its showing a graph which is dynamically changing.I think problem is with your layout or anything else.post your whole xml layout .

Comment: thank you for replying, I have edited my question to include the full xml code. It's good to know that the example works though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
The problem is with your layout, it is not designed well.
```

Use something like the following. You may need to adjust few things.
Your layout is not showing properly on small screen devices.I have edited ur layout and now its showing on small devices also.Please adjust height and other things according to ur requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AccValues"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Accelerometer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/gl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <requestFocus />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Now Recording Data to file. Press button to add name to file" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ETName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Name Here"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxWidth="200dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/baddNametoFile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="Add Name to File" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Stop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF0000"
                android:text="Stop Recording" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABSGS "
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="164dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: where are u running ur app?

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately it still isn't appearing. I'm running it on my tablet, Nexus 7 2013

Comment: see what i m getting, I think problem is something else if it still not working.

Comment: I'll keep trying, thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: Quick Question, should I have to add anything to my manifest if I bring the code in from somewhere else?

Comment: It depends on what u are bringing, if activity or service then u will need to tell manifest.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43839/discussion-between-gurfuffle-and-keshav)